# Visual Studio 2017 with CUDA cannot open include file 'cuda.h'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I am working on the Nvidia SDK with Visual Studio and I have been running into the error of this whenever I am trying to compile the sample from Nvidia:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
 Error  C1083   Cannot open include file: 'cuda.h': No such file or 
directory   AppDecPerf
 c:\users\administrator\desktop\video_codec_sdk_8.1.24\samples\appdecode\appdecperf\appdecperf.cpp  12

I do have CUDA installed on my computer and it looks like I have to link it with the IDE somehow but I just cannot find 'cuda.h' file anywhere.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should just use the windows find file utility to find `cuda.h` on your machine.  You would then have to add whatever the path is to that file, to your project include path settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install cuda library( static or dynamic) for Windows in vc++ 2017 using vcpkg.exe. Use `.\vcpkg integrate install` to automatically link the project to your solution.

Use `.\vcpkg install cuda:x64-windows-static` to install.

Comment: '.\vcpkg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Use poweshell. Change directory to location of vcpkg.exe if path is not registered.

Comment: vcpkg is something you clone from github and build isn't it?

Comment: @DeanSchulze: Yes

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project, choose `Build Dependencies` then `Build Customizations`. From here you can choose the version of the CUDA Toolkit that you'd like to work with (amongst other things it will add the `$(CudaToolkitDir)` variable, and a new `CUDA C/C++` tab to the project properties). The samples from NVIDIA should already be configured this way, but I've noticed that they can break when upgrading the SDK.

Further details are available here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#build-customizations-for-existing-projects